# How to force my array to be a specific length - Java

Tags: java, arrays, declaration

I have an object described by the class QAData. It includes the following properties:
String to hold text which asks a question.
Array of Strings holding exactly 4 possible answers.
Array of Boolean holding exactly 4 right/wrong options corresponding to the answers.
Array of Boolean holding exactly 4 options indicating whether an option was selected by the user.

My question is how I can force the array to be of length 4 in my initial class below?

```
public class QAData {
    private String questionText;
    private String[] answerText = new String[4];
    private Boolean[] correctAnswer = new Boolean[4];
    private Boolean[] selectedAnswer = new Boolean[4];

    QAData(String questionText, String[] answerText, Boolean[] correctAnswer, Boolean[] selectedAnswer){
        this.questionText = questionText;
        this.answerText = answerText;
        this.correctAnswer = correctAnswer;
        this.selectedAnswer = selectedAnswer;
    }

    public String getQuestionText(){
        return this.questionText;
    }

    public String[] getAnswerText(){
        return answerText;
    }

    public Boolean[] getCorrectAnswer(){
        return correctAnswer;
    }

    public Boolean[] getSelectedAnswer(){
        return selectedAnswer;
    }

    public void setSelectedAnswer(Boolean[] selectedAnswer){
        this.selectedAnswer = selectedAnswer;
    }
}
```

Comment: The arrays are initially instantiated with a length of 4. But in your constuctor you re-instantiate your arrays with the passed arrays. Do you want to check if your passed arrays have a length of max 4? You can do that like `if (array.lenght > 4) {throw new IllegalArgumentException();}`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In fact, the fields instantiation here is useless :

```
private String[] answerText = new String[4];
private Boolean[] correctAnswer = new Boolean[4];
private Boolean[] selectedAnswer = new Boolean[4];
```

As these will be overwritten in the constructor :

```
QAData(String questionText, String[] answerText, Boolean[] correctAnswer, Boolean[] selectedAnswer){
    this.questionText = questionText;
    this.answerText = answerText;
    this.correctAnswer = correctAnswer;
    this.selectedAnswer = selectedAnswer;
}
```

The single way to control the arrays length is checking that in the constructor and the methods that sets the arrays. 
**Note that less you provide mutable methods in your class, more consistency rules are simple to guarantee**.

Here is an example to guarantee the array length in the constructor :

```
QAData(String questionText, String[] answerText, Boolean[] correctAnswer, Boolean[] selectedAnswer){
    assertLengthIs4(answerText, correctAnswer, selectedAnswer);       
    this.questionText = questionText;
    this.answerText = answerText;
    this.correctAnswer = correctAnswer;
    this.selectedAnswer = selectedAnswer;
}

public void assertLengthIs4(Object[]... arrays){
       for (Object[] array : arrays){
           if (array == null || array.length != 4){
               throw new IllegalArgumentException("size should be 4 for all arrays");
           } 
       } 
}
```

Comment: `public void assertLengthIs4(String[]... arrays)` should be `public void assertLengthIs4(Object[]... arrays)`

Answer (score 0):

The Java Arrays API offers this functionality:

```
Arrays.copyOf(T[] original, int newLength)
```

This will truncate/pad the array to the new length.